# Broken Picking Coordinates Directx11

Tags: math, mfc, directx, directx-11

I have for a fair while now been trying to implement a click-based model insertion into my game editor but have run into numerous problems. The most recent is an offset in the placement of the model. So far I have got this code together:

```
    D3DXVECTOR3 vPickRayDir;
    D3DXVECTOR3 vPickRayOrig;

    float width = (float)d3d->scd.BufferDesc.Width;
    float height = (float)d3d->scd.BufferDesc.Height;

    const D3DXMATRIX* pmatProj = &d3d->matProjection;

    POINT ptCursor;
    GetCursorPos(&ptCursor);
    ScreenToClient(&ptCursor);

    D3DXVECTOR3 v;
    v.x = (((2.0f * ptCursor.x) / (d3d->viewport.Width)) - 1.0f) / pmatProj->_11;
    v.y = -(((2.0f * ptCursor.y) / (d3d->viewport.Height)) - 1.0f) / pmatProj->_22;
    v.z = -1.0f;

    const D3DXMATRIX matView = d3d->matView;
    const D3DXMATRIX _matWorld = matWorld;

    D3DXMATRIX matRotateX, matRotateY, matRotateZ, matTranslate;

    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate, 0, 0, 0);
    D3DXMatrixRotationX(&matRotateX, 0);
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY, 0);
    D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&matRotateZ, 0);

    matWorld = (matRotateX * matRotateY * matRotateZ) * matTranslate;

    D3DXMATRIX mWorldView = matWorld * matView;
    D3DXMATRIX m;
    D3DXMatrixInverse(&m, NULL, &mWorldView);

    vPickRayDir.x = v.x * m._11 + v.y * m._21 + v.z * m._31;
    vPickRayDir.y = v.x * m._12 + v.y * m._22 + v.z * m._32;
    vPickRayDir.z = v.x * m._13 + v.y * m._23 + v.z * m._33;
    vPickRayOrig.x = m._41;
    vPickRayOrig.y = m._42;
    vPickRayOrig.z = m._43;

    ModelInstance mi(GetDocument()->GetModel(m_wndModels.m_nodeTree.selectID));

    mi.Translation.at(0).x = (1 * vPickRayDir.x + vPickRayOrig.x);
    mi.Translation.at(0).y = (1 * vPickRayDir.y + vPickRayOrig.y);
    mi.Translation.at(0).z = (1 * vPickRayDir.z + vPickRayOrig.z);
    mi.Translation.at(0).z *= -1;
```

Why is there an offset and how do I remove it?

P.S. [Here's a link the complied program](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B31ZpbBZ5QAMY1N3ODNfc05HejA/view?usp=sharing). Click open and open the enclosed fbx file. Once opened, double click the model in the model list and click on the view space to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/553768-d3dxvec3unproject-and-mouse/). The last post showed everything that was needed, all I needed to do was change variables to suit DirectX-10.